# LibreOffice: Changing corporate colors in documents

Tags: colors, libreoffice

We have a lot of corporate documents. These contain colors: colors of foregrounds, backgrounds, graphical elements. Let us assume management wants us to change colors.

Is it possible to search/replace a color?

Can I give a color a name, so that if I later change the definition of this name, then it will change in all corporate documents?

Answer (score 0):

For new documents, just replace the LibreOffice (LO) document templates at each workstation.

For existing documents, though it is *possible* to search and replace a color or style, since LO documents are stored using PK-Zip compression, each file would need to be opened (whether with a third-party tool or LibreOffice), modified and re-saved. Furthermore, any encrypted documents would need to be opened using the password.

However, [when an old document is opened after a new template is loaded, LO asks if any old *styles* specified in the document should be updated.](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/20408/how-do-i-update-styles-in-my-document-from-a-template/) Staff could be instructed to accept these changes for any old documents before releasing them again.

See LibreOffice [documentation on templates](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.2/HTML/GS5203-StylesAndTemplates.html).

All this is predicated on the original documents using *styles*, rather than being manually modified or copied from a master document (as opposed to template).